# How to copress image before uploading with android?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, bitmap

I am uploading some images through my app, some images because of their size are not able to be uploaded...  How to solve this ?
Please help

```
 if (requestCode == pickImageCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            table = data.data
            val arrayOfData = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            val myImageQuery = view!!.context.contentResolver.query(table, arrayOfData, null, null, null)
            myImageQuery.moveToFirst()
            val columnIndex = myImageQuery.getColumnIndex(arrayOfData[0])
            imagePath = myImageQuery.getString(columnIndex)
            myImageQuery.close()
            val myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)
            imageToInSendLayout.setImageBitmap(myImage)


        } else {
            return
        }

        imageUri = data.data
```

Preview image into imageView before sending to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is(sorry for the java version, I don't have the kotlin one anywhere around :) ):

```
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bounds);
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bounds, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, opts);
```

where

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (reqWidth != 0 & reqHeight != 0) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                        && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

What happens is: you decode file data, then, by passing reqwidth/reqheight you make it smaller. Then you can pass it to your layout :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the lib Picasso:

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(path)
    .resize(sizeW, sizeH)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(target)
```